# No matching function call to 'pthread_create' in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, parameters, pthreads

No matching function call to 'pthread_create'

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <pthread.h>

string nextProduced;
string nextConsumed;
char *BUFFER;
int BufferSize = 10;
void putItemIntoBuffer();
string produceItem();
string consumeItem();
void *Producer();
void *Consumer();

pthread_cond_t Buffer_Not_Full=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t Buffer_Not_Empty=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mVar=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main()
{
pthread_t pro, con;

BUFFER=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BufferSize);

pthread_create(&pro,NULL,Producer,NULL);// Creates threads 

pthread_create(&con,NULL,Consumer,NULL);// Creates threads 

pthread_join(pro,NULL);

pthread_join(con,NULL);


return 0;
```

}

Xcode gives me the error, "No matching function call to 'pthread_create'". I dont know what i'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was able to get it to compile but i am now getting this message.
I do not know what the problem is.
thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread

```
libsystem_c.dylib`strlen:
0x7fff8d8364e0:  pxor   %xmm0, %xmm0
0x7fff8d8364e4:  movl   %edi, %ecx
0x7fff8d8364e6:  movq   %rdi, %rdx
0x7fff8d8364e9:  andq   $-16, %rdi
0x7fff8d8364ed:  orl    $-1, %eax
0x7fff8d8364f0:  pcmpeqb(%rdi), %xmm0 Thread 1:EXC_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) //line in question
0x7fff8d8364f4:  andl   $15, %ecx
0x7fff8d8364f7:  shll   %cl, %eax
0x7fff8d8364f9:  pmovmskb%xmm0, %ecx
0x7fff8d8364fd:  andl   %eax, %ecx
0x7fff8d8364ff:  je     0x7fff8d83650b            ; strlen + 43
0x7fff8d836501:  bsfl   %ecx, %eax
0x7fff8d836504:  subq   %rdx, %rdi
0x7fff8d836507:  addq   %rdi, %rax
0x7fff8d83650a:  ret    
0x7fff8d83650b:  pxor   %xmm0, %xmm0
0x7fff8d83650f:  addq   $16, %rdi
0x7fff8d836513:  movdqa (%rdi), %xmm1
0x7fff8d836517:  addq   $16, %rdi
0x7fff8d83651b:  pcmpeqb%xmm0, %xmm1
0x7fff8d83651f:  pmovmskb%xmm1, %ecx
0x7fff8d836523:  testl  %ecx, %ecx
0x7fff8d836525:  je     0x7fff8d836513            ; strlen + 51
0x7fff8d836527:  subq   $16, %rdi
0x7fff8d83652b:  jmp    0x7fff8d836501            ; strlen + 33
```

Comment: The function pointer passed to `pthread_create` should be for a function which takes a `void*` argument.  Can you try changing `Producer` and `Consumer` to do this?  i.e. `void *Producer(void* arg);`

Comment: In the future when posting questions regarding compiler or linker errors, please provide the *complete* and *unedited* error log. There are often more messages that may help with answering what's wrong.

Comment: @simonc that helped but now i get Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your producer and consumer functions should be as follows:

```
void *Producer(void *data);
void *Consumer(void *data);
```

I believe you are required to pass the attributes parameter as well. See [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) for a good example.